# Install Windows Service during Setup installation using VS2010

Tags: c#, windows-services, setup-project

I have windows service as separate Ser.exe file. It will install using command prompt with Installutil -i "Ser.exe path".

Also,
I have setup project [like this](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2014/01/how-to-create-setup-for-window.html)  for windows application.

Now , I want to install Ser.exe during setup install. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

-Firstly add your Ser.exe to the Installation Directory
-In Solution exp right click set-up project >>View>>Custom Actions>>Install right-click >>Add Custom Action 
-now give the path of Installation Directory to reach Ser.exe then click OK(This wil execute the command prompt installation for you)

I have tried separate project for service set-up and it simply works for me

-First of all create a separate service project
-Then create a set-up project and select primary output from your service project.

Comment: When using installer classes to install the service you need to add ALL the custom action nodes, including uninstall. or the service won't be removed when you uninstall the product.